# Error in list view for android application?

Tags: android, listview, tabwidget

Hi all I have tab in my project. within my main tab i am having two sub tabs. Upto this tab its working finely. When i integrate pnr tab its raising error in list view.

```
pnr_cnfrm_item_list_view.setVisibility(View.GONE); //  got an error in this line
```

my pnr code is [here](http://pastie.org/8361695) .
my error is [here](http://pastie.org/8361700).

[image]

I dont know where i did the mistake. Can anybody tell me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exception are you getting? NPE?

Comment: @asha-u just comment typeface and run your project again and tell u fill facing the same problme-because sometime typeface interruption error this type of...

Comment: finally i resolve the error. I have created this layout for all resolution. It can be run in mobile only not in tablet. Actually i forget to update my layout in all the .xml file so only this error would came. Finally i found it and resolved it to. Thanks for your valueable time and suggestions...